# Reword tour page to specify best practices in specific cases

Tags: discussion, scope, help-center, wording

This is my own fault, but if I made the mistake I'm sure others could too. I missed that "Best practices in general" was in the "Don't ask about section" because I stopped at "Best practices and design pattern usage" in the "Ask about" section.

Is is possible to maybe reword it to something like

- Best practices *for specific cases*
- Design pattern usage *for specific cases*
- Security issues
- Performance
- Correctness in unanticipated cases

*Looking at it again though, maybe that is what was meant by "The quality of your working code with regards to:"*

The issue I see is that there's two things so similar in each list, it's like saying "Ask q if q is ∈ A; Don't ask q if q ∈ B, where B ⊂ A".

Comment: I agree, something needs to be done about this part.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Ditto.  `Ask about ... best practices`, but `Don't ask about ... best practices in general.`  Also, in "Don't ask," the example `it's okay to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice regarding X?"` seems to me opposite in sense to `Don't ask about ... best practices in general.`  (But I'm brand-new here, so don't have enough information to make any concrete suggestions :) )